# Unset a post PHP... Does not want to unset

Tags: php, post, unset

Hello so I been trying to unset a post, basically the issue I am having is that the data gets INSERTED into the database. The php function sends out the message stating that the post was successful. That is all good but when I refresh my page, the post keeps on INSERTING data into my database. Basically how can I stop it from posting. Here is the code:

```
            if(isset($_POST['submit_message'])) { 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (user_id, timestamp, times, message) 
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".date("Y.m.d")."', '".date("H:i:s")."', '".$_POST['message-content']."')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    unset($_POST['submit_message']);
    unset($GLOBALS['_POST']['submit_message']);
    if(!$result) {
        $msg = 'There was an error while trying add your message.'; 
        unset($_POST['submit_message']);            
    } else {
        $msg = 'Your message was successfully added.';      
        unset($_POST['submit_message']);        
    }
            }
```

As you can see from the code I tried inputting some unset posts using PHP but that does not seem to work. How can I unset my post?

Comment: It works, when I refresh my page the INSERT keeps on INSERTING. Basically I want to unset so it wont happen again.

Comment: Why do u need to unset it anyway? Copy the value to a separate array and modify that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you refresh the page, the form data is resubmitted. As a result `$_POST` is freshly populated with the form data. Remember, HTTP is stateless. Once the page executes and the request terminates the POST data from that request is gone.

If you do not want a page refresh to resubmit the form, you need to use the [POST/REDIRECT/GET](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168) pattern.

> In order for this to work properly we need to use a 303 redirect. This means we need to send a 303 header with our redirect. A 303 redirect will cause the browser to reload the page without the initial HTTP POST request to be resubmitted. This includes when the user uses the back or refresh buttons.

Comment: Yea how can I terminate the POST?

Comment: @JohnConde it may help for you to quote the text of item 3 from the solution in the "POST/REDIRECT/GET" pattern explanation since that part explains how the 303 redirect prevents the re-submission of the form in the event that the browser navigates to the page in the history stack.